# How do I check Mobile Application's Code base as a layman?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, codebase

I'm doing research around a series of mobile applications that exist in the Google Play and Apple App store. We're trying to avoid apps that have been built in SwiftUI as references.

Is there a way to relatively easily check what the code base is for an app from the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

The codebase of commercial (and often non commercial apps as well) are usually closed source. So the developers don't expose the source code to the public.
So to answer your question "Is there a way to relatively easily check what the code base is for an app from the App Store?". No, unfortunately not. You might have luck and look for the app name + "github". In case the app's source code is open source, it is likely hosted on github.

Comment: OK perfect. Thank you: D